# iTunesConnect test user verifying

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I create iTunes connect test user, but when I am trying to test in-app-purchase, my app in iOS simulator says, that i need to verify my apple id. How can I do it?

Text of error view:

```
You haven't verified your apple id.
Tap OK to see instructions.
```

When I taps OK, it hides alert view and it is end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found problem. Now we must use our real email and they will send email to verify it.

Comment: That's not going to work since the email is unique - I'm not creating a new email account every time I want a new test user.

Answer (score 2):

This has been happening to quite a lot of people in the last couple days and there is a thread in the Apple Dev Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/128982?tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

No need to verify it,
Actually its a dummy account for testing purpose. So, if you enter dummy email id which is not exist will be fine. And if you try to enter real email id, then it send you verification mail. But don't worry if you're not verify that that will work fine.
But better you should apply dummy email id instead your real email id to avoid this confusion...!?!

Answer (score 2):

It's some times happens. But you can test in-app purchase with test user.

Just make sure below points:

1) You test the app in device (not simulator).

2) Before test the in-purchase, you should be logged out from app store on device.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this issue and it seems there is a simple way to rectify the issue.

Issue:

After creating an Apple ID(best to use a fake email that doesn't exist to reduce headache) for a test user account in Albania, I signed out of the normal Apple ID I use from within "Settings>iTunes & App Stores" and leave it signed out. 
Then I start the app I'm testing, attempt to purchase anything within the app, at which point I'm prompted with a message that asks to use existing Apple ID or Create New Apple ID. 
I choose the Use Existing Apple ID option.
Then I'm prompted to enter email & password.
This is where you enter the test user account info you've created in iTunes Connect.
After entering the test user account info, a message saying that this profile/account has not been verified/used on this market previously, then I tap "OK", and it redirects me to the App Store.

**At this point do not do anything further within the app store or the prompts that appear within it, it will just create further confusion/problems**

Instead, back out of the store, and re-open the app your testing. At this point, try to purchase that same item again and it should work just fine.
I have no idea why it redirects you to the app store to begin with, but for whatever reason it does. It does seems strange that in-app purchase testing would ever re-direct you to the store, but it just does, so try to ignore the idiocy and move on. Just pretend it didn't happen, and go back into your app as if nothing happened and everything makes sense.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

We all have to file bug report to Apple so that it gets addressed faster. AFAIK Apple does not really care about discussions in their devforums.

And yes, I started experiencing the very same problem since Oct 21.